# PHP array getting updated for some reason

Tags: php, arrays, mx-record

Take a look at this code:

```
$names = array();
$names[] = "abc.com";
$names[] = "def.com";
$names[] = "ghi.com";

$myrecords = array();

foreach ($names as $key => $value) {

    getmxrr($value, $mxrecords);
    $myrecords[$value] = $mxrecords;

}

print "<pre>";
var_dump($myrecords);
print "</pre>";
```

this code seeks to get the MX records of domains and just print it out. I am making a new array with the domain as key and the value being the retrieved MX records.

The problem is that for some reason, the $mxrecords array is replaced every time so basically the last domain has the mx records and the others show up empty. If i go remove the "ghi.com" domain, then the last domain would be "def.com" and that then suddenly has the mx records showing up.

Comment: It may help, if you create your own $mxrecords array. I don't know, how the getmxrr function is defined, but it seems that it uses the second parameter as reference *getmxrr($value, &$mxrecords)*. So a solution is to create a separate $mxrecords for each iteration of your loop

Comment: show us getmxxr function, it probably use $mxrecords as reference

Comment: getmxxr It's a native function

Comment: it is built in function

Comment: what output do you expected?

Comment: i even tried making the $mxrecords have dynamic name but still same result

Comment: I'm not sure, what your problem is, but the code you provided works fine - which php version are you using? some very old php4?

Comment: @Philipp the problem is that only the last domain is populated with the mx records,

Comment: Just tested it, and that isn't the case `$myrecords` contains the mx records for every domain of `$names`

Comment: Hey Jimmy, can you try to initialize the `$mxrecords` var before the loop ? Since it is passed by reference to the `getmxrr` function, it may cause some problem ?

Comment: seem like the getmxrr were write into the mxrecords pointer which refer in the myrecords so i recommend to clear the mxrecords before call to getmxrrr just set $mxrecords = [] in beginning of foreach

Comment: i have done that, still same issue